# Upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 22.04

With the release of the 22.04 LTS coming up, I have been given some old 16.04 units and tasked with getting them upgraded to 22.04 when it's released. I understand these units should've been upgraded a long time ago and that this process may not be very straightforward.

*Realistically, what is the best way to move from 16.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS?* These units do not have a lot of storage space so I don't think do-release-upgrade is an option.

Details:

```
uname -r
4.10.0-42-generic
```

```
cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
```

Comment: Realistically there's no such upgrade. Install 22.04 from scratch.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu. Back up all your changed system config files, user data, non-standard software, test your backups, and do a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04LTS and restore the backups. Read the release notes for 18.04, 20.04, 22.04. Check the hardware requirements for Ubuntu 22.04. Will Ubuntu 22.04LTS even fit on the "old units"?

Comment: Also, some applications behave differently or are plainly incompatible with the upgraded packages installed with the new distros or even worse, are no more included. Check, for example, if there are PHP 5.6 apps that use deprecated functions in the new PHP 8.0/8.1 packages of U22. Also, some configurations have to be analized and rewritten, for example, /etc/network/interfaces are superseded by /etc/netplan/*yaml files.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Do you have ESM enabled?   Your system needs to be fully-upgraded to perform `do-release-upgrade` which requires ESM to be enabled so you can apply all upgrades/fixes for your *xenial* system.  If you don't have ESM enabled; the [Ubuntu Release Upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tool will detect that & refuse to upgrade; where upgrades will be to 18.04 only.. You'll then need to reboot, upgrade to 20.04, then wait till *after* 22.04.1 is out which opens the path from 20.04 upgrades.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: The *best* method will depend on how you used the servers, what applications & setups were involved; none of which was provided, so ask an administrator of the system for the best clues.  Without knowing that detail; the only obvious solution is to backup, clean install the new system & restore data backups - then deal with any *fallout*, as we cannot predict *fallout* with specific server knowledge & apps used & configurations in use...